# Rorty's Pragmatism

Tags: pragmatism, rorty

When I've heard famous philosophers speak or read their writing, I have usually been impressed by their reasoning and insight even if I didn't agree with them. Richard Rorty is an exception. I recently listened to a podcast where he was discussing neo-pragmatism and I was appalled at how lame his argumentation was. He would, for example, say that we should stop being hung up by grand notions of truth or justice and just rely on the outcomes of ideal conversations between people.

Every time he was challenged, he would slip aside and deny that he was making any positive claims. For example, "What is it that makes an ideal conversation if not that the conditions of the conversation are likely to lead to truth?" or "What is the goal of these conversations if it's not justice?" He equivocates, saying he doesn't deny the existence of truth or justice, only that they can be defined or that we should be concerned about them.

Is this a common criticism of Rorty? I can't imagine how he seems to have been take so seriously in the philosophical community.

Comment: One reading, he is attemping to hasten the meta-conversation through unproductive/unpragmatic terrain

Comment: "Unproductive/unpragmatic terrain" seems to be a staple of the discipline.

Comment: Something along these lines is common, albeit in more polite terms, see e.g. [post about Rorty](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/34255/9148) that quotes Zammito's book on post-positivism:"*Rorty has executed several elegant turns through Gadamer and Heidegger to come more and more to partner with Derrida... Rorty dissolves too many distinctions; his new "pragmatism" entails a cavalier disdain for rational adjudication of dispute... History and sociology of science has become so "reflexive" that it has plunged "all the way down" into the abime of an almost absolute skepticism*".

Comment: Susan Haack called his approach vulgar, a caricature of classical pragmatism (full text [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/311536965_Vulgar_Pragmatism_An_Unedifying_Prospect_1995)). Since I haven't read that essay yet, I just post a comment here. I would behave like Rorty if I made an answer out of it. But to be fair, he's not all bad. He [predicted Trump](https://www.vox.com/policy-and-politics/2017/2/9/14543938/donald-trump-richard-rorty-election-liberalism-conservatives). Maybe he just chose the wrong job and should've specialized as a social commentator.

Comment: Your question is not very well sourced.  Could you provide some specific details corroborating your description of Rorty's arguments?  I would like to request of fellow users to refrain from closing this *question* until such clarifications are provided.